# Namespace resolution inside preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, header, namespaces, preprocessor

I have a `.h` header shared among a C executable and a large C++ codebase.

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace my {
#endif

typedef int my_t;

#define MY_OH_MY sizeof(my_t)

typedef my_t alias_t;

// plenty of other typedefs which push me to keep only
// these two bracing #ifdef __cplusplus ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // namespace
#endif
```

The C source works well with the exclusion.

```c
#include "my.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    my_t m = 1;
    alias_t a = 2;
    m += MY_OH_MY;
    return 0;
}
```

However the CXX source fails under Gnu compiler:

```cpp
#include "my.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    my::my_t m = 1;
    my::alias_t a = 2;
    m += MY_OH_MY;
    return 0;
}
```

> my.h:7:25: error: ‘my_t’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘my::my_t’?
> 7 | #define MY_OH_MY sizeof(my_t)

Basically because (?) at preprocessor time are namespace still not a thing ?
I was expecting that in any case it would have fallen within the `namespace { }` enclosing group.

I can surely change it to the following, but I still cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define MY_OH_MY sizeof(my::my_t)
#else
    #define MY_OH_MY sizeof(my_t)
#endif
```

Comment: Macros perform textual replacement. It's as if you did `m += sizeof(my_t);` directly in `main()`.

Comment: Why use a macro when you can just use a proper variable?

Comment: Because that macro will be used across the codebase in several other macros and I can't refactor a whole repository just because of a single sub-optimal choice.

Comment: Inside the C++ `main`, do what the preprocessor does: replace the text `MY_OH_MY` with `sizeof(my_t)`. The problem should become clearer.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: why macro instead of constexpt inline variable?

Comment: The answer is: project constraint is to share a header also with C modules. If the problem admits no solution, the correct answer would simply be: there ain't no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use namespaces (as it is not a feature of  C language) in C identifiers that must be accessed from C.  Indeed, you must declare those specially in order for the compiler not to mangle the names.  You can only use them in C++, but be carefull as to share code with C, you must inform the C++ compiler which routines and what identifiers will be visible from C (the compiler mangles the names in a different way to include info about operator definitions, parameter lists and overloading, and namespaces) resulting in identifiers completely cryptic to the programmer.

To see an example, just write this function:

```
char *function1(char *parameter1, int parameter2)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it as C language (naming the file with `.c` suffix) and with C++ language (using `.cc` as file suffix).  Then use `nm(1)` to see the names the compiler used to name your function.
###As C code (in file `func.c`):

```
$ make func.o
cc  -O2 -pipe -c func.c -o func.o
$ nm func.o
0000000000000000 T function1
$ _
```

###Now as C++ code (in file `func.cc`):

```
$ make func.o
c++ -O2 -pipe -c func.cc -o func.o
$ nm func.o
0000000000000000 T _Z9function1Pci
$ _
```

The `_Z` indicates something to the compiler, the 9 indicates an identifier 9 characters long (`function1`), The `P` is for a pointer, `c` is for `char` and `i` if for integer parameters.

If you have compiled it in C++, but declared it inside an `extern "C" { }` block, then the name would have been the same as in the first example, but you should not be able to define another function with name `function1` and different parameter list, as there's already a C function named `function1`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* C++ functions that will be accessible from C code, or C function
 * declarations that will be accessed from C++ code, depending on which
 * source you include this code */

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```